# Ordered Nested lists similar to Microsoft WORD numbered nested lists

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem, nesting

In `LaTeX`, by default the numbering styles change depending on the depth of the nested lists as shown below.

```
\begin{enumerate}
   \item First level item
   \item First level item
   \begin{enumerate}
     \item Second level item
     \item Second level item
     \begin{enumerate}
       \item Third level item
       \item Third level item
       \begin{enumerate}
         \item Fourth level item
         \item Fourth level item
       \end{enumerate}
     \end{enumerate}
   \end{enumerate}
 \end{enumerate}
```

**Output of the above**:

[image]

**Question**: In `LaTeX`, how can we achieve something similar to nested numbered lists in Microsoft WORD, as shown below?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this easily with the `enumitem` package.

The `enumitem` package allows you to determine the numbering system for any level or all levels of a list class.  In this example, I've used:

```
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\theenumi.\arabic*.,ref=\theenumi.\arabic*}
```

This means "set the label of the second level of `enumerate` to be the label of the first level (`\theenumi`) plus the arabic number representation of the current level (`\arabic*`)."

Since you likely don't want a dot after the number in references, I've added a separate specification for references that excludes it.  If you want to do this for other levels, you can add a format for each sublevel:

```
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\theenumi.\arabic*.,ref=\theenumi.\arabic*}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label=\theenumii.\arabic*.,ref=\theenumii.\arabic*}
```

The toplevel counter is `enumi`, the next level is `enumii`, etc. The output representation of those counters is `\theenumi`, `\theenumii`, etc. So each definition has to refer to the representation of the counter of the previous level in its definition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\theenumi.\arabic*.,ref=\theenumi.\arabic*}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
   \item First level item
   \item First level item
   \begin{enumerate}
     \item Second level item
     \item Second level item
   \end{enumerate}
 \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Your suggestion works (thank you). Could you please explain the line `\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\theenumi.\arabic*.,ref=\theenumi.\arabic*}`. For example, when I changed `enumerate,2` to `enumerate,3` in the above line it changed the second level numbering to alpha (a) Second level (b) Second level. When I changed from 2 to 4 or 5, it did not do anything. I'm just trying to understand so I can use your suggestion in some other cases, as well.

Comment: @nam I've updated the answer with some more detail. Does that help?

Comment: That's exactly what I was after. And thank you for adding your explanation in your original response as it may help other readers, as well.